# import cannot find a module I just installed via the same program

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, import, pip

I am writing a python installer script that needs to install 2 additional modules via pip inside the script, then import and use those modules to finish the installation in the same script. The pip call works fine, but when I attempt to import the module (*winshell*) I just installed, I get an error that it cannot import another module (win32con) which is part of the second module I installed (*pywin32*).

If I re-run the script after the error, everything works like it should, so I know the actual pip installs are working correctly. I seems like the running python script just doesn't know about some of the installed modules until the program is re-run. Is there a way to make a running script "update" the modules it sees available without having to re-run the program?

Here is the simplified code:

```
import os
import sys
try:
    from pip import main as pipmain
except ImportError:
    from pip._internal import main as pipmain

def create_shortcut():
    print 'Creating shortcut...'
    import winshell

    link_filepath = os.path.join(winshell.desktop(), "Start.lnk")
    with winshell.shortcut(link_filepath) as link:
        link.path = sys.executable
        link.description = "Shortcut to startup"
        link.arguments = r"C:\temp\my_program.py"

def install_requirements():
    print 'Installing requirements...'
    pipmain(['install', '-r', 'wheelhouse/requirements.txt', '--no-index', '--find-links', 'wheelhouse'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    install_requirements()
    create_shortcut()
```

Here is the error:

```
C:\temp>python my_installer.py
Installing requirements...
Looking in links: wheelhouse
Collecting pywin32>=224 (from -r wheelhouse/requirements.txt (line 1))
Collecting winshell>=0.6 (from -r wheelhouse/requirements.txt (line 2))
Installing collected packages: pywin32, winshell
Successfully installed pywin32-224 winshell-0.6
Creating shortcut...
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "my_installer.py", line 24, in <module>
create_shortcut()
   File "my_installer.py", line 10, in create_shortcut
import winshell
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winshell.py", line 30, in <module>
     import win32con
ImportError: No module named win32con
```

When I run the second time (and the modules are already installed):

```
C:\temp>python my_installer.py
Installing requirements...
Looking in links: wheelhouse
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=224 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from -r wheelhouse/requirements.txt (line 1)) (224)
Requirement already satisfied: winshell>=0.6 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from -r wheelhouse/requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.6)

Creating shortcut...

C:\temp>
```

Comment: Can you give more details about your code? and also the exact error message you get ! It would help understand better what the issue might be

Comment: Can you edit with the exact error? The question is way too vague

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution that I would recommend you to check:

try installing `pypiwin32` using `pip install pypiwin32`

This problem does not seem to be related to your code, but rather to the module installation itself. I still find it weird since it works well when you run it the second time, but still worth giving a try

Answer (score 0):

If you install new modules during a program's execution, you need to [invalidate the module finder caches](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.invalidate_caches) to make sure the import system sees the new modules:

```
import importlib
importlib.invalidate_caches()
```